# WebProvisioned event handler is firing twice and subsite does not inherit the parent's top navigation

Tags: event-receivers, event-handlers, web-template

I have created an web event receiver but the webprovisioned event handler fires twice. I have set the scope to web, but it still fires twice.

**Problem 1**

This is elements file:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers Scope="Web">
    <Receiver>
      <Name>WebEventReceiverWebProvisioned</Name>
      <Type>WebProvisioned</Type>
      <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
      <Class>WebEventReceiver</Class>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>         
    </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Event:

```
    public override void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties)
    {
    SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Web
web.Navigation.UseShared = true;
    web.Update();
    }
```

I saw another post which mentioned that if the scope is set to web it will fire only once, but it my case it is still firing.

**Update 1**

I tried the following code. It sets the options correctly, but they are not applied to the UI yet. I have to click OK once again to see the changes.

Just to be sure that you guys get what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to set the **top navigation**, not the left navigation.

```
                    // PublishingWeb Navigation
                    var pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);

                    var webNavigationSettings = new WebNavigationSettings(web);


                    webNavigationSettings.GlobalNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.InheritFromParentWeb;


                    webNavigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.PortalProvider;
                    pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludeSubSites = true;
                    pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludePages = true;
                    pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentDynamicChildLimit = 20;

                    pubWeb.IncludeInGlobalNavigation = true;
                    pubWeb.Navigation.InheritGlobal = true;
                    pubWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludeSubSites = true;
                    pubWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludePages = true;

                    webNavigationSettings.AddNewPagesToNavigation = false;
                    webNavigationSettings.CreateFriendlyUrlsForNewPages = false;

                    webNavigationSettings.Update();
                    pubWeb.Update();
                    web.Update();
```

**Problem 2**

When I create a new site the top navigation does not get applied to this newly created site.Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You might have a couple instances of the same event receiver attached. You can check by running the following PowerShell commands and look for duplicates:

If you attach event receivers to a site collection:

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$site = Get-SPWeb http://webapp/sites/SiteCollection
$site.EventReceivers | sort Type | ft Class, Type
```

If you attach event receivers to a web:

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb http://webapp/sites/SiteCollection/web
$web.EventReceivers | sort Type | ft Class, Type
```

For your second problem, try using the following code:

```
var web = properties.Web as SPWeb;
var pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
pubWeb.InheritGlobalNavigation = true;
pubWeb.Update();
```

or

```
var web = properties.Web as SPWeb;
var pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
pubWeb.Navigation.InheritGlobal = true;
pubWeb.Update();
```

You might need to update `web` object as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

The EventReceiver is normal. Please change the scope of your Feature where the EventReceiver is provisioned from Web to WebApplication Scope or create a new one and add your EventReceiver to a WebApplication scoped Feature.

**Problem 2**

And here is the solution for your navigation problem https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms196088(v=office.14).aspx.

```
childWeb.Navigation.UseShared = true;
```